# How to check the Year EDT lenght?

Tags: variables, types, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I created a Table's *Field*, and in addition to this, I created my custom EDT, named : **MyEDT** (for example).

*MyEDT* is *INTEGER* type and I have extended the System standard EDT *YearBase*.
So, if I insert the alphabetic characters (look like "abecjskjfh") I get an error.

But I need to have a  rule, I want to insert only value with 4 Number character, I only want values look like : 2000 , 2006, 1982 etc... .

I can check/control this by code, in methods *validateWrite* or *validateField* I insered this code :

```
switch (p1)
{
 case fieldNum(MyTable, MyField)  :   
           if (strLen( (strFmt("%1",this.MyField)) ) != 4)
           throw error ("Inser only value AAAA");
           break;
}
```

But,It's possible or exist to creato or axtends the YEAR EDT with only 4 number char length ? Or, there is another way to check the length the field valu ?

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an integer EDT, I think there is no way to restrict the range of allowed numbers, except the `AllowNegative` property. So you have to do the validation in code like in your question. But I would suggest to change your validation logic to validate a number range instead of casting the number to a string and then validating the number of characters. This way you could also make sure that users cannot enter a year like 0000.

```
if (this.MyField< 1900 || this.MyField > 9999)
{
     throw error("Please enter a year between 1900 and 9999");
}
```

Another possibility could be to use a date EDT where you set the `DateYear`, `DateMonth` and `DateDay` properties such that only the year is shown. This would also help with data entry (e.g. 2 gets replaced with 2002) and gives you a nice error dialog if the users enters for example "abc".

[image: Screenshot of example using date EDT that only shows the year]

Answer (score 1):

You can use X++ [`match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa886279.aspx) function.

`match('<:d:d:d:d>','2004')` would match all 4 digit string (0000-9999).

`match('<[12]:d:d:d>','2004')` would match string 1000-2999.

Alternate way is to use [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx)`('1234', '^\d{4}$')`